# Extract API request log in cloudwatch

Tags: python, regex, string, transform, etl

I'm looking ways to extract each of fields in below payload in Cloudwatch. This payload is not proper json format. Any suggestion to transform it to proper json format? Or store each fields in single variable using regex?

```
log = "{Date=Wed, 03 Mar 2021 01:33:41 GMT, Content-Type=application/json, Content-Length=11841, Connection=keep-alive, x-amzn-RequestId=427382d7-1234-5678-1234-a2022c4d0796, x-amzn-Remapped-Content-Length=0, X-Amz-Executed-Version=$LATEST, X-Amzn-Trace-Id=root=1-123ee774-1234c16635364cda21e42155;sampled=0}"
```

Which desirable output:

```
{"Date": "Wed, 03 Mar 2021 01:33:41 GMT", "Content-Type": "application/json", "Content-Length": 11841, "Connection": "keep-alive", "x-amzn-RequestId": "427382d7-1234-5678-1234-a2022c4d0796", "x-amzn-Remapped-Content-Length": 0, "X-Amz-Executed-Version": "$LATEST", "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "root=1-123ee774-1234c16635364cda21e42155;sampled=0"}
```

If cannot transform directly, what I think of doing using regex for each fields such as

```
request_id = re.search(r'\bx-amzn-RequestId:\s+(\w+(?:-\w+)+)\s+', log).group(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

since YAML is a superset of JSON, you can do:

```
import yaml
log = "{Date=Wed, 03 Mar 2021 01:33:41 GMT, Content-Type=application/json, Content-Length=11841, Connection=keep-alive, x-amzn-RequestId=427382d7-1234-5678-1234-a2022c4d0796, x-amzn-Remapped-Content-Length=0, X-Amz-Executed-Version=$LATEST, X-Amzn-Trace-Id=root=1-123ee774-1234c16635364cda21e42155;sampled=0}"
log = log.replace(","," ",1) #Replace first occurrence of a , in a string (Wed, 03 Mar 2021 01:33:41 GMT is Wed 03 Mar 2021 01:33:41 GMT)
json_data = yaml.load(log)
final_dict = {}
for key in json_data.keys():
    split_data= str(key).split("=")
    final_dict.update({split_data[0]: split_data[1]})
print(final_dict)
```